# iOS Facebook paper like popover view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, facebook, uiviewcontroller

As the title says I'm looking for a way to implement a view controller which presents itself in the same way as the Facebook Paper's notifications / messages / friend requests view controllers.

What I would like is to have an icon (like the one in Facebook Paper) and when the user taps on it a new view controller would pop up in pretty much the same animated way as in paper (since I think that one can hardly polish that animation any further `=)`). I want it to be a view controller since it will be doing some lifting that I want to be separated which means a `UIView` instance is not welcome.

Any clues on how to roll such a view controller?
I'm guessing that the parent controller (the one that displays all the news) is actually a `UIContainerViewController` which adds the child one to itself and then animates it's view in that particular way.

I have managed to find something similar - the [WYPopoverController](https://github.com/nicolaschengdev/WYPopoverController). Which looks like a shot in the right direction but would need some extra work and polish to accomplish that same effect and smoothness. I will probably take a deeper look at it if needed but was hoping that you guys might have something better at your disposal. :)

Any leads or clues would be much appreciated.

*PS. If you have any issues understanding what I mean (like if you haven't seen Paper) let me know in the comments and I will get some images in the post as well.*

**EDIT:**
[Here is a video showing off the feature.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-uNyXqC0Mpo&t=2m55s) If you replay it enough times the entire animation is visible good enough. I'm not after the bounce of the icon (at least not as much) as I'm more interested in that transition itself. Can still provide more photos if needed though.

Comment: Afaik paper app is only available in the us. You might be better recording it from your phone or something.

Comment: @Fogmeister agreed. I've edited the post to reflect the feature better.

Comment: OK, just writing something up now.

Comment: did you see my answer? You haven't commented or voted or accepted it. Thanks

Comment: @Fogmeister saw it and am thrilled that you took the time and wrote it. I just haven't found the time to implement it and so can't tell if it suits my needs. As soon as I implement it I will accept it. I promise.

Comment: No worries. Just checking :-)

Comment: Any update on this at all? Just wondering if you got it sorted?

Comment: @Fogmeister I ended up using [WYPopoverController](https://github.com/nicolaschengdev/WYPopoverController) which I modified a bit to animate with a spring animation and so far it's working quite well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I did a similar thing with a calendar "pop over" type view which you can see [on my blog](http://www.oliverfoggin.com/animate-with-springs/).

It isn't exactly what you're looking for but I think you'll be able to get a very close match.

I was using a storyboard in the app that I made that calendar for so I'll write this using a storyboard too.

First thing to not is that the calendar part of the app uses a whole new ViewController to manage it. Doing this did a couple of things.

1. It meant I could keep the code for the calendar separate to the code for the view controller that used it. This made it super easy to maintain. If the calendar needed fixing I did it in the calendar view controller.
2. It made the calendar super easy to use in any part of the app that needed it. Because it was in its own view controller I just needed to present it and it could be used anywhere.

**So... how I would do yours.**

Create your view controller called something like `MyPopoverViewController` and add it to the Storyboard. Now create a modal segue from whichever view controller you want to present it from. Even from a button if that's what you want. Make the segue modal. And make it have no animation.

What this will do is instantly switch from your current VC to the `MyPopoverVC`.

Now you need a couple of properties in the .h file.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *backgroundView;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint startPoint;
```

Now, in the VC that is calling it you need to have your prepareForSegue method something like this...

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"myPopoverSegue"]) {
        MyPopoverVC *controller = segue.destinationViewController;

        controller.backgroundView = [self.view snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:NO];
        controller.startPoint = // the position of the button that was pressed
    }
}
```

**Now to set up the popover view controller**

First, make sure the backgroundView property is added to the self.view.

```
[self.view insertSubview:self.backgroundView atIndex:0];
```

Also make sure the backgroundView is the same size as the screen.

Or you can do this in the storyboard. What this does is it takes the snapshot of the view of the previous view controller and puts it at the back of the new view controller. This makes it look like the popover is appearing over the old VC when in reality it's just a screenshot. Without this the new VC will have a plain black background (or whatever colour you set).

**What about the start point**

In view did load do something like this...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...
    self.theViewYouWantToBounce.frame = CGRectMake(self.startPoint.x, self.startPoint.y, 0, 0);
    ...
}
```

This will place it at the start point (where the button was) and give it zero size.

I'm assuming you have auto layout turned off in this to keep things simple.

OK, so now. In `viewDidAppear`...

```
- (void)viewDidAppear
{
    [super viewDidAppear];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0.0
             usingSpringDamping:1.0
          initialSpringVelocity:1.0
                        options:0
                     animations:^{
                         self.theViewYouWantToBounce.frame = CGRectMake(//the end frame of the view
                     }
                     completion:nil];
}
```

You'll have to tweak the settings (damping, initial velocity) but this will bounce the view from the current size (0,0) at the start point out to the size and position you want it to be.

To hide it just do an animation back to zero size before dismissing the view.

I hope this makes sense.

Things to remember.

1. Do it in a new view controller.
2. Fake it to look like it's in the same VC (using the snapshot).
3. Make the view really small at the start point.
4. On view did appear animate it out to the size you want.

Hope this helps.